# POTS over LAN - Need additional "land" line telephone extensions without running more wire

Tags: telephony

Looking to extend POTS service to a couple outbuildings using an existing LAN connection (so we don't need to trench more wires).

I'm familiar with the ObiTalk devices, so my first thought was to forward all the calls to Google Voice but that's not ideal because there are no local GV numbers available (meaning we would incur long-distance charges for every call we answer on the new extension).

What I'm envisioning is some sort of FXO gateway that would make the phone service available to Obi devices (or similar) elsewhere on the network.

Comment: Would VOIP work here? I'm not super knowledgeable about telephone networks and how they interact with Ethernet/LAN lines.

Comment: That's basically the idea - adapters do exist for plugging analog phones into a VOIP system. Main part I'm struggling with is a cost-effective way to get the analog POTS signal into the network to begin with.